# Using PPC Title/Description in landing pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-ads-api

I'm trying to create some dynamic landing pages for my site. Specifically we're going to be using google ads to link to the page. I'd prefer to only have one landing page that dynamically updates based on the google ppc ad that was clicked. My first try was using utm parameters in the url like so:

http://www.example.com/?utm_title=Title&utm_description=Description&utm_coupon=FREESHIP&utm_coupon_description=get%20free%20shipping

and parsing the string with purl and jquery, updating the title, description, coupon and coupon description on my page. I've tested it, and this part works, but I've been told that wont work with google adwords?

Is there a better/another way to do this? Or am I stuck creating a bunch of different landing pages?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is doable using [*ValueTrack* parameters](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2375447) in the destination URLs of your ads. In your case, the `{keyword}` and `{creative}` parameters could be of interest.

I don't know though if having a landing pages dynamically generated based on those parameters is a legal practice under the Adwords ToS, though. You might want to check on that.